# i need software to decode this subtitle xml file, anyone know what it encodes with?

Tags: decompilation, radare2, decryption, deobfuscation, decompiler

This is a subtitle file encoded by xml, is there any way to decode this xml file to srt?

[Subtitle link xml](https://s.gohitv.com/subtitle/e97bda54a96c4565b1929812fecda6d91665026261591.xml)

Comment: Any background info on the file? Where's it from?

Comment: it comes from here, i want to download this subtitle file is there any way to decode it

https://www.gohitv.com/series/vi-vn/love-is-for-suckers?frm=home&frmnav=wn_vdDzLAubEu3LkUvr_qDe&frmblk=wm_9LsNsy9dm4W_EHS0e_gQ

Comment: Can you create a script that only decodes the xml file.

Answer (score 6):

It's AES encrypted, but fortunately it's pretty trivial to see what's going on in the JavaScript file responsible for decoding (https://www.gohitv.com/series/js/hiplayer.min.js) by using browser debugging tools.

Here's a code snippet for decoding that I've tidied up based on the JS file above:

```js
(function() {
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("52e3d76bf3115bbd");
    const vector = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("62543816fdce10e7");

    // First <con> element from XML file
    const encoded = "XSTDxIM1NI+9kYheVJG7ywPKAmg7YNtRKmvhLt6R5umov1aFpyEXrZopsQiHBBBfjrr052rcchm8JBlxY8c47mwz8hUw72VjmqQEna3GHRI=";
    const decoded = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encoded, key, {
        iv: vector,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

    return decoded; // TÊN NGƯỜI, TỔ CHỨC, TÌNH TIẾT TRONG PHIM\NKHÔNG CÓ THẬT.
})();
```

You will need CryptoJS: https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/

---

**Edit:** I've wrapped this all up in a Python script which you can find [here](https://github.com/sapphire-bt/hitv-subtitles).

In terms of reverse engineering the process, this is how the decrypting happens:

1. Find the episode ID (search the page source for `eid="..."`)
2. GET request to `https://api.gohitv.com/s1/w/series/api/episode/detail` with `eid` param and `did` param (random 24 char ID)
3. The response includes a timestamp and encrypted base64 data. To decrypt the data:

   1. Create MD5 hash #1 of `did` (from step 2) + the timestamp
   2. Create MD5 hash of hash #1 + `Wcb26arWkvkcAZc378eR` (a hardcoded key in the site's JavaScript)
   3. Use the first 16 bytes of hash #2 as the AES key and the last 16 bytes as the vector
4. GET request to `https://api.gohitv.com/s1/w/series/api/series/rslv` with the following params:

   - `eid` - episode ID
   - `scid` - source ID (from step 3)
   - `sid` - series ID (from step 3)
   - `sq` - seems to always be `1`
   - `sign` - MD5 hash of: query string of above values + `bywebabcd1234` (another hardcoded key)
5. Find subtitle data in response (includes download URL + key)
6. Decrypt the subtitle contents using the key as outlined in step 3.3

Comment: Sorry I haven't come back here in a few months, thank you for helping me, but there is one thing I can ask you, where did you find the key and vector? Can this be earned on the app?

Comment: @ĐứcNguyễn take a look at the `GET` requests to `api.gohitv.com`. Each request has a `did` header (which is a random 24 char string) and returns a timestamp along with encrypted base64 data. Calculate `md5(md5(did + timestamp) + "Wcb26arWkvkcAZc378eR")` - first 16 bytes is the key, last 16 bytes is the vector. The `Wcb2 ...` value is a hardcoded AES key on the page.

Comment: Hello, I just now have time to revisit this article. Can other urls be downloaded? Can other episodes be watched on the mobile app? Can I get subs, for example:
https://www.gohitv.com/series/vi-vn/love-is-for-suckers/7?frm=home&frmnav=wn_vdDzLAubEu3LkUvr_qDe&frmblk=wm_9LsNsy9dm4W_EHS0e_gQ

Comment: I got the error Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
How can I use it? Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't know about the mobile app as I only tried with the free links; you might be able to include your session token/login details in the requests.

Your error sounds like it could just be your firewall.

I suggest opening an issue on the GitHub page if you have any issues with the script - as far as reverse engineering goes, this has been solved and the question should be marked as completed.